# Error when making fcgi dev kit

Tags: c++, fastcgi

I'm trying to install fcgi dev kit.
But when I make it, below error was showed.
Can't anyone help me?
Thank so much.

```
**[chivo@localhost fcgi-devel-kit]$ make
(cd libfcgi; make all)
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/chivo/fcgi-devel-kit/libfcgi'
gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -g  -I../include   -c -o fcgi_stdio.o     fcgi_stdio.c
In file included from fcgi_stdio.c:42:0:
../include/fcgios.h:94:21: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
../include/fcgios.h:94:21: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
fcgi_stdio.c:54:1: error: initializer element is not constant
fcgi_stdio.c:54:1: error: (near initialization for ‘_fcgi_sF[0].stdio_stream’)
fcgi_stdio.c:54:1: error: initializer element is not constant
fcgi_stdio.c:54:1: error: (near initialization for ‘_fcgi_sF[1].stdio_stream’)
fcgi_stdio.c:54:1: error: initializer element is not constant
fcgi_stdio.c:54:1: error: (near initialization for ‘_fcgi_sF[2].stdio_stream’)
make[1]: *** [fcgi_stdio.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chivo/fcgi-devel-kit/libfcgi'
make: *** [all] Error 2**
```

I'm using fedora 14, gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4). And I have downloaded newest version of fcgi_dev_kit on this sit: http://www.fastcgi.com/om_archive/applibs/

Comment: What is the version of your libfcgi and the compiler you used ?

Comment: FastCGI Developer's Kit 2.0b2 AND gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)
I'm using fedora 14.

Answer (score 0):

The version you are trying to build is very old and has some incompatibilities with current systems. I got errors at the configure stage.

I tried the newer version at the homepage and event that one gave errors (trivial) at the compiling stage.

You better fetch the latest version and continue with that...

Comment: This project i have to use fedora 14 only. I thinks FastCGI Developer's Kit 2.0b2 is the latest version.

Comment: No, the package contents are dated 1997, 17 years ago. The latest package is from 2003. http://www.fastcgi.com/dist/fcgi.tar.gz

Comment: I have build this package but not success. Other error has showed.